# unable to use the link that was appended

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a website, that is just like a blog. I am able to show all the posts from the database but unable to show individual post because I cannot select the link that I appended.

````
$.ajax({       
url: '/get/all',       
contentType: 'application/json',       
success: function(response){        
 response.data.forEach(function(d){           
 var title = d.title;           
 var  content = d.recipie;            
 var author = d.author;            
 var idrecipie = d.idrecipie;
 $('#contentdiv').html("");         
 $("#maindiv").append('<h1> <a id="link" href="/get/'+idrecipie+'">'+title+'</a></h1>');         
});      
 }     
}); 
});```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you can open correctly the page namely `/get/'+idrecipie` from your browser tab, than there's no reason your anchor would not work. Please open Dev tools, inspect your element. Does the href looks OK? Does the Network tab has any errors?